# Alternative for delete

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

In previous versions of Actionscript, you could use `delete` in conjunction with `Object.registerClass('name', null)` to delete class definitions at runtime. Now, according to Adobe documentation, `delete` will only remove any dynamically attached properties, leaving the core object or definition lingering in memory.

Is there a way to completely remove a class definition (not just an instance) at runtime in Actionscript 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, no.

In AS3, you can only delete members of dynamic objects.  You've probably already googled and found this, but: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/understanding_t.html.

You can segregate definitions by using multiple ApplicationDomains, but I guess this isn't quite what you're looking for.

Comment: what happens if you loaded and external swf with some new class definitions and then unloaded it? (my guess is that those definitions stick, but if not...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yep, I've googled around and found that, but was hoping that there was *some* alternative in AS3.

Comment: @gltovar: Yes, the definitions stick around (unfortunately).

Comment: @shanethehat: re. segragated ApplicationDomain: If you unload the root of an ApplicationDomain (I'm assuming that you can use a child domain), would the definitions for that domain be gc'd?

Comment: It'd be worth a test.  Without trying, my guess is that it will depend on the application domain used for loading the swf. If you use `ApplicationDomain.currentDomain` then they should stick after unloading, and if not you're putting your faith in the GC. It's still not going to be an option for immediately deleting something.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the input - I'll give 'er a go.. Too bad we can't force GC :P

Comment: And of course you have the headache of working with multiple application domains

Comment: So, what I ended up trying was to create a map (object) and assign a new ApplicationDomain to it (for deletion later, as you *can* delete dynamic objects). I ran a quick test to see if the class definition would be deleted and that's when I ran into the facepalm of "ugh.. I can't *access* that definition anymore as the accessor has been deleted. One would *assume* that the class definitions assigned to that appdomain would be GC'd, but unless there's a method that I can't think of atm (my brain hurts), I can't actually *confirm* it.